Issue with Friedman test in GraphPad Prism
I am analyzing the GC-rich to AT-rich cell-free DNA fragment number ratio in the whole genome context and different genomic (gene, repeat, etc.), epigenomic (heterochromatin, euchromatin), and regulatory contexts (TSS, CpG). The sample size is 243, all are blood samples from healthy individuals. My objective is to find out if the GC-rich to AT-rich cell-free DNA fragment number ratio differs across different contexts. So I am considering this as a paired sample scenario.
In GraphPad Prism, I have conducted normality tests (D'Agostino & Pearson test, Anderson-Darling test, Kolmogorov-Smirnov test), and most of the groups were not normally distributed. I have also conducted outlier detection analysis using the ROUT method, and no outliers were found. Then, to compare between groups, I chose the options for the "paired sample" and "non-parametric" tests. Hence, Prism automatically selected Friedman's test with Dunn's post hoc analysis. Prism didn't allow to change the test type. However, when I plotted the test results, it seemed like boxplots that are very near to each other (with overlapping data points) have 4-star statistical significance (e.g. TFCBS and DNase HS), while boxplots that are very distant to each other without any overlap are non-significant (CpG Islands and TSS).

Then I did some online research and found that Dunn's post hoc analysis is not suitable for paired samples. In one thread I found that Holm's method is more suitable for post hoc analysis combined with Friedman test and Wilcoxon sign rank test for paired samples. Since Prism didn't allow me to do any other tests, I used R to perform these tests. I used the following code:
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(rstatix)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)

file_path <- "C:/Users/asira/OneDrive/Desktop/De/Corrected/GC/gc_to_at_rich_fragment_ratios.tsv"
df <- read.csv(file_path, sep = "\t")

# Function to filter data beyond the 5th and 95th percentiles
filter_extremes <- function(data, value_col) {
  quantiles <- quantile(data[[value_col]], probs = c(0.05, 0.95), na.rm = TRUE)
  data %>% filter(Value < quantiles[1] | Value > quantiles[2])
}

# Function to apply the Friedman test and plot boxplots
plot_with_friedman_significance <- function(data, columns, title) {
  # Reshape data for ggplot in specified order
  data_melted <- data %>%
    select(Sample_ID, all_of(columns)) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -Sample_ID, names_to = "Group", values_to = "Value")
  
  # Filter data to show only points beyond 5th and 95th percentiles
  filtered_data <- filter_extremes(data_melted, "Value")
  
  # Perform the Friedman test
  friedman_test_result <- friedman_test(data_melted, Value ~ Group | Sample_ID)
  
  # Print the Friedman test result
  cat("Friedman Test Result:\n")
  print(friedman_test_result)
  
  # Convert the data to ranks for post-hoc testing
  data_melted <- data_melted %>%
    group_by(Sample_ID) %>%
    mutate(Rank = rank(Value)) %>%
    ungroup()
  
  # Perform pairwise comparisons on the ranks
  pairwise_test_results <- pairwise.wilcox.test(data_melted$Rank, data_melted$Group, 
                                                p.adjust.method = "none", paired = TRUE)
  
  # Extract raw p-values
  post_hoc_results <- as.data.frame(pairwise_test_results$p.value) %>%
    rownames_to_column(var = "group1") %>%
    gather(key = "group2", value = "p.value", -group1) %>%
    filter(!is.na(p.value))
  
  # Adjust p-values manually and print them after each pairwise comparison
  post_hoc_results <- post_hoc_results %>%
    mutate(
      p.adj = p.adjust(p.value, method = "holm"),
      p.adj.signif = case_when(
        p.adj <= 0.001 ~ "****",
        p.adj <= 0.01 ~ "***",
        p.adj <= 0.05 ~ "**",
        p.adj <= 0.1 ~ "*",
        TRUE ~ "ns"
      )
    ) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(
      output = paste("Comparison:", group1, "vs", group2, 
                     "| p-value:", p.value, 
                     "| Adjusted p-value:", p.adj, 
                     "| Significance:", p.adj.signif)
    ) %>%
    ungroup()
  
  # Print each comparison result
  post_hoc_results %>% pull(output) %>% cat(sep = "\n")
  
  # Manually add y-position for annotations
  max_y <- max(data_melted$Value, na.rm = TRUE)
  step_increase <- max_y * 0.05
  post_hoc_results <- post_hoc_results %>%
    mutate(y.position = max_y + (1:n()) * step_increase)
  
  # Create the boxplot
  p <- ggplot(data_melted, aes(x = factor(Group, levels = columns), y = Value, fill = Group)) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    geom_point(data = filtered_data, aes(x = factor(Group, levels = columns), y = Value), color = "black", alpha = 0.5) +
    labs(title = title, y = "Value", x = "") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
    guides(fill = "none")
  
  # Add significance annotations (NS or asterisks)
  p <- p + geom_signif(
    comparisons = combn(columns, 2, simplify = FALSE),
    annotations = post_hoc_results$p.adj.signif,
    y_position = post_hoc_results$y.position,
    tip_length = 0.01,
    textsize = 3
  )
  
  # Print the final plot
  print(p)
}

# Define columns for each context
genomic_columns <- c("whole_genome", "knownGene", "RepeatMasker", "telomere", "Centromere")
epigenomic_columns <- c("whole_genome", "strongheterochromatin", "weakheterochromatin", "interchromatin", "weakeuchromatin", "strongeuchromatin")
regulatory_columns <- c("whole_genome", "TSS_peaks", "CpG_Islands", "DNase_HS", "TF_ChIP", "TF_Clusters")

# Plot and test for each context, ensuring comparisons are only within each context
plot_with_friedman_significance(df, genomic_columns, "Genomic Contexts")
plot_with_friedman_significance(df, epigenomic_columns, "Epigenomic Contexts")
plot_with_friedman_significance(df, regulatory_columns, "Regulatory Contexts")

I got the following output:
> plot_with_friedman_significance(df, genomic_columns, "Genomic Contexts")
Friedman Test Result:
# A tibble: 1 × 6
  .y.       n statistic    df         p method       
* <chr> <int>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>        
1 Value   243       972     4 4.17e-209 Friedman test
Comparison: knownGene vs Centromere | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 8.79351360628624e-54 | Significance: ****
Comparison: RepeatMasker vs Centromere | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 8.79351360628624e-54 | Significance: ****
Comparison: telomere vs Centromere | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 8.79351360628624e-54 | Significance: ****
Comparison: whole_genome vs Centromere | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 8.79351360628624e-54 | Significance: ****
Comparison: RepeatMasker vs knownGene | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 8.79351360628624e-54 | Significance: ****
Comparison: telomere vs knownGene | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 8.79351360628624e-54 | Significance: ****
Comparison: whole_genome vs knownGene | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 8.79351360628624e-54 | Significance: ****
Comparison: telomere vs RepeatMasker | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 8.79351360628624e-54 | Significance: ****
Comparison: whole_genome vs RepeatMasker | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 8.79351360628624e-54 | Significance: ****
Comparison: whole_genome vs telomere | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 8.79351360628624e-54 | Significance: ****
> plot_with_friedman_significance(df, epigenomic_columns, "Epigenomic Contexts")
Friedman Test Result:
# A tibble: 1 × 6
  .y.       n statistic    df         p method       
* <chr> <int>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>        
1 Value   243      1215     5 1.66e-260 Friedman test
Comparison: strongeuchromatin vs interchromatin | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: strongheterochromatin vs interchromatin | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: weakeuchromatin vs interchromatin | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: weakheterochromatin vs interchromatin | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: whole_genome vs interchromatin | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: strongheterochromatin vs strongeuchromatin | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: weakeuchromatin vs strongeuchromatin | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: weakheterochromatin vs strongeuchromatin | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: whole_genome vs strongeuchromatin | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: weakeuchromatin vs strongheterochromatin | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: weakheterochromatin vs strongheterochromatin | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: whole_genome vs strongheterochromatin | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: weakheterochromatin vs weakeuchromatin | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: whole_genome vs weakeuchromatin | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: whole_genome vs weakheterochromatin | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
> plot_with_friedman_significance(df, regulatory_columns, "Regulatory Contexts")
Friedman Test Result:
# A tibble: 1 × 6
  .y.       n statistic    df         p method       
* <chr> <int>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>        
1 Value   243      1215     5 1.66e-260 Friedman test
Comparison: DNase_HS vs CpG_Islands | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: TF_ChIP vs CpG_Islands | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: TF_Clusters vs CpG_Islands | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: TSS_peaks vs CpG_Islands | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: whole_genome vs CpG_Islands | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: TF_ChIP vs DNase_HS | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: TF_Clusters vs DNase_HS | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: TSS_peaks vs DNase_HS | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: whole_genome vs DNase_HS | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: TF_Clusters vs TF_ChIP | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: TSS_peaks vs TF_ChIP | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: whole_genome vs TF_ChIP | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: TSS_peaks vs TF_Clusters | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: whole_genome vs TF_Clusters | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****
Comparison: whole_genome vs TSS_peaks | p-value: 8.79351360628624e-55 | Adjusted p-value: 1.31902704094294e-53 | Significance: ****

As you can see, I am getting very similar p-values across different pairs. However, all the group comparisons appear to be highly statistically significant. I am very confused about whether I am doing anything wrong, or if this is expected. Please let me know if there is an issue with my code or the statistical tests I am choosing.

(Big problem of empty precision in the R output!)

Why do you consider these samples paired? That would usually entail some clustering in your measurements (within condition), for example GC content before and after some kind of intervention. This seems like a standard two-sample case (or however many groups you have).

@MichaelLew Could you please elaborate? Thanks.

@PBulls I considered these samples as paired because all these contexts (gene, repeat, CpG, etc.) are measured from each healthy person's whole genome cell-free DNA sequence. In the raw data file I am analyzing, each row is a single person (with a unique ID), and each column is the GC to AT-rich fragment number ratio in different genomic contexts. There were 243 rows corresponding to 243 persons. Those contextual values were measured computationally from a single whole genome sample of each person. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.

15 significant figures on a p-value does not add any information that has an practical purpose, but it does have the serious disadvantage of making the number difficult to read and understand.
